# In CSS, what is the difference between ::first-letter and :first-letter?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

Running through some test preparation, I was asked if this would set the first letter color correctly:

```
td.one::first-letter {
    color:blue;
}
```

Now, I know I've seen places where the colon is doubled-up on, but a test jsFiddle doesn't show any difference in behavior between that and

```
td.two:first-letter {
    color:green;
}
```

So, I'm just curious what the difference is, and why you would use :: instead of : in front of the pseudo-class?

http://jsfiddle.net/mori57/bqE7Q/

Comment: In my defense, do you know how difficult it is to get a clear search result between : and :: on Google? :) I'll take my lumps, however... need to work on my spec-reading stamina! Thanks for the input, all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're equivalent in this case, but only because it's a pseudo-element, not a pseudo-class. The double-colon syntax was created in order to prevent the confusion arising from calling single-colon pseudo-elements "pseudo-classes" (which your question demonstrates, oddly enough). From the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#pseudo-elements):

> This `::` notation is introduced by the current document in order to establish a discrimination between pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements. For compatibility with existing style sheets, user agents must also accept the previous one-colon notation for pseudo-elements introduced in CSS levels 1 and 2 (namely, `:first-line`, `:first-letter`, `:before` and `:after`). This compatibility is not allowed for the new pseudo-elements introduced in this specification.

If you're not planning on supporting IE < 9, it is best to denote all your pseudo-elements with double colons going forward. If you require support for older versions of IE, you can continue using single colons, but only for the aforementioned selectors.

Comment: Until I asked this question, I hadn't thought about the distinction between a pseudo-element and a pseudo-class before. Thank you very much for rolling in the specific portion of the spec, and the additional information.

Comment: So, using `::first-letter` would be referencing a pseudo-element, whereas `:hover` denotes a pseudo-class? Just found this interesting explanation of the difference between the two, for anyone else confused (as I was) about the difference: http://www.d.umn.edu/~lcarlson/csswork/selectors/pseudo_dif.html

Comment: Yes, `:hover` is one of the few [UI states pseudo-classes](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#UIstates)

Comment: @mori57: That's correct. A pseudo-element is an imaginary element that's part of a real element, whereas a pseudo-class is a sort-of "state" that a real element can be in. In your example, `::first-letter` represents the first letter of an element's text content, whereas `:hover` represents the element itself when it is in the hover state.

Answer (score 4):

Checked the spec?

> This :: notation is introduced by the current document in order to
>   establish a discrimination between pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements.
>   For compatibility with existing style sheets, user agents must also
>   accept the previous one-colon notation for pseudo-elements introduced
>   in CSS levels 1 and 2 (namely, :first-line, :first-letter, :before and
>   :after). This compatibility is not allowed for the new pseudo-elements
>   introduced in this specification.

http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#pseudo-elements

Comment: I must have been looking at the wrong page in the specs... I searched on the document for :: and didn't see this! But then again, my eyes do start to glaze over a bit at times looking at these, so thanks for pointing out the pertinent bit! Will mark your answer as soon as SO lets me. :)

Comment: No worries, but you should probably accept someone else's answer, such as BoltClock's. He gives more of an explanation, I just linked to the spec.

Comment: Fair enough. Yours was the first one I read, and it was clear enough from that snippet, though it of course didn't specify the IE-issue. I just tend to naturally assume I will need to check out caniuse.com for more specialized selectors, anyhow. Thanks again!